# Wine virtual drive set to network location?

Tags: 12.04, wine, samba

I've currently got all of my music saved on a NAS server, and want to play it on my Ubuntu machine as well as Windows, which works fine using Linux music software.

The problem is I'm so obsessed with Foobar2000 (Windows music player), that I'd rather have that running under Wine to play music on. If I try to create a virtual drive in Wine pointing to the network location it doesn't work, Foobar2000 can't find any music there.

Alternatively, if I create a Samba share of my local music folder, Wine recognises the location and I can play music from there, and I can also access the folder from Windows. This works great, but I'd rather be storing my music on the NAS server.

So, is there any way I can integrate a remote network location into Wine, so that programs in Wine can access the Network? Like how I'm using the Samba share, but files stored on a server?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution.

Network Locations are found in /home/user/.gvfs, so linking Wine to there works.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. By posting it here you've hopefully helped someone else down the road with the same issue.

Comment: cannot find `/home/user/.gvfs` on MAC OS